# Help solving NSXMLParser error 39 : NSXMLParserAttributeNotStartedError

Tags: xml, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsxmlparser

I've been searching for about two hours now trying to find out what this error is and how to solve it. Apple's documents gladly says

> NSXMLParserAttributeNotStartedError
>   Attribute is not started. Available in
>   Mac OS X v10.3 and later. Declared in
>   NSXMLParser.h.

but fails to provide any help whatsoever. Can anyone help me out here? Any nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

In viewDidLoad, I have:

```
NSURL *xmlUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:xmlFilepath];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlUrl];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
```

No problems with getting the xml, I can successfully read up until the root element, then it breaks.

The rest of the related code goes like:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"foo"]) {
  foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 } else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"bar"]) {
  bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
 }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)attributeName forElement:(NSString *)elementName type:(NSString *)type defaultValue:(NSString *)defaultValue {
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"bar"]) {
  if ([attributeName isEqualToString:@"barAttrib1"]) {
   [bar setBarAttrib1:[defaultValue intValue]];
  } else if ([attributeName isEqualToString:@"barAttrib2"]) {
   [bar setBarAttrib2:defaultValue];
  } 
 }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
 // nothing inside the elements, just attributes
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"bar"]) {  
  [foo addObject:bar];  
  [bar release];
  bar = nil;
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: example xml

```
<foo>
  <bar barAttrib1=1 barAttrib2="hello" />
  <bar barAttrib1=2 barAttrib2="world" />
</foo>
```

Comment: Please post the example XML too

Comment: +1 for asking a very good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is XML, then quotes are *REQUIRED* around the attribute value.  Try

```
<foo>
  <bar barAttrib1="1" barAttrib2="hello" />
  <bar barAttrib1="2" barAttrib2="world" />
</foo>
```

Note the quotes around the values of `barAttrib1`

Comment: arr... But of course. >.<
I must be way too stressed out that I overlooked that. I'll try that once I get back to the office tomorrow. Thanks!